# Как организовать Consumer для многопоточного кода?

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня поиск который собирает `txt` файлы в очередь `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, и потом в нескольких потоках одновременно проверяет содержимое этих файлов на соответствие заданной строке. В общем многопоточный поиск файла содержащего какую-то строку. Когда один из потоков находит заданную строку, он останавливает все остальные. Сам обход файловой системы у меня выполняется в отдельном потоке.

Для пула потоков использую `ExecutorService`.

Вот такой `Consumer`:

```
public class ConsumerSearch implements ConsumerGetter<File>, Consumer<File> {
    private File result = null;

    @Override
    public void accept(File result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    @Override
    public File getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}
```

Вот общий класс который создает потоки:

```
public class ParallelSearch implements Parallel {
    private AtomicReference<ConsumerSearch<File>> consumer;
    // останавливает все потоки (вызывает cancel в цикле по threads).
    private final Stopper stopper;
    // лист запущенных потоков.
    private final List<Future<File>> threads;
    // размер пула потоков.
    private final int amountThreads;
    // очередь в которой храняться файлы.
    private final Queue<File> container;
    private final ExecutorService service;

    public ParallelSearch(final int amountThreads, Consumer<File> consumer) {
        this.service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(amountThreads);
        this.amountThreads = amountThreads;

        this.container = new LinkedTransferQueue<>();
        this.consumer =  new AtomicReference<>(consumer);
        this.threads =   new ArrayList<>(amountThreads);
        this.stopper =   new Stopper();
    }

    @Override
    public AtomicReference<Consumer<File>> getConsumer() {
        return consumer;
    }

    @Override
    public void killConsumer() {
        this.consumer.set(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void startParallelSearch(
            final String pathToRoot,
            final String targetText) {

        this.searchByFileSystem(pathToRoot);
        this.searchByFilesContent(targetText);
    }

    // поток обходит файловую систему в поисках txt файлов и добавляет в очередь.
    private void searchByFileSystem(final String pathToRoot) {
        final Thread searchByFileSystem = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CollectingTXTFiles(
                        pathToRoot, container)
                        .collectTXTFromRoot();
            }
        });
        this.service.submit(searchByFileSystem);
    }

    // добавляем в пул потоки для поиска строки по содержимому txt файлов
    private void searchByFilesContent(final String targetText) {
        for (int i = 0; i < (this.amountThreads - 1); i++) {
            final Future<File> taskRead =
                    this.service.submit(new Callable<File>() {
                        @Override
                        public File call() throws Exception {
                            return new SearchByFileContent(container, stopper, ParallelSearch.this)
                                    .scanQueue(targetText);
                        }
                    });
            // добавляем в потоки поиск контенту
            this.threads.add(taskRead);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Останавливает все потоки ссылка его экземпляр есть у всех потоков.
     * Если один из потоков найдет искомую строку, вызовет stopAllSearchingThread().
     */
    class Stopper {
        void stopAllSearchingThread() {
            for (Future future : threads) {
                future.cancel(true);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Вот так выглядят сами потоки:

```
public class SearchByFileContent implements SearchByFile {
    private final Queue<File> paths;
    private final ParallelSearch.Stopper stopper;
    private final Parallel parallelSearch;

    public SearchByFileContent(final Queue<File> paths,
                               final ParallelSearch.Stopper stopper,
                               final Parallel parallelSearch) {
        this.stopper = stopper;
        this.paths = paths;
        this.parallelSearch = parallelSearch;
    }

    @Override
    public File scanQueue(final String target) {
        while (this.paths.size() != 0 && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            final File next = this.paths.poll();
            final File result = getFileWhichContains(target, next);

            if (result != null && !result.getName().equals("-1")) {
                if (parallelSearch.getConsumer() != null) {
                    synchronized (parallelSearch.getConsumer()) {
                        if (this.parallelSearch.getConsumer().get() != null) {
                            this.parallelSearch.getConsumer().get().accept(result);
                            this.parallelSearch.killConsumerReference();
                            this.stopper.stopAllSearchingThread();
                            return result;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return new File("-1");
    }

    private File getFileWhichContains(final String target, final File file) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (file == null) return new File("-1");
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(file))
        ) {

            String line;

            while (Objects.nonNull(line = reader.readLine())) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            if (new String(sb).contains(target)) {
                return file;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new File("-1");
    }
}
```

Вызываю вот так:

```
@Test
public void whenThen() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    ConsumerSearch<File> consumer = new ConsumerSearch();
    Parallel parallel = new ParallelSearch(5, consumer);
    parallel.startParallelSearch(dir.getAbsolutePath(), "test");

    final File result = consumer.getResult();
    Assert.assertThat(result.getName(), is("test2.txt"));
}
```

Иногда работает, иногда падает с `NullPointerException` в предпоследней строке теста `final File result = consumer.getResult()`. Хотя вроде все логично и должно работать. Помогите поправить эту проблему.

Comment: в какой строке возникает NPE?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman в тесте предпоследняя строка: final File result = consumer.getResult();

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Comment: `this.searchByFileSystem(pathToRoot);
this.searchByFilesContent(targetText);` вот эти две строки у вас могут выполняться параллельно, а по смыслу насколько я понял `searchByFilesContent` должен стартовать строго после `searchByFileSystem`. То есть внутри `searchByFilesContent` вы запускаете в `Executor`е `this.service.submit(searchByFileSystem);` и сразу же, не дожидаясь выполнения, запускаете `this.searchByFilesContent(targetText);`. Это вроде как неверно, нужно дождаться окончания чтения списка файлов.

Comment: @iksuy не совсем идея в том что сбор файлов в очередь идет паралельно ссканированием файлов на результат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо потому, что файл еще не успел найтись, а вы делаете getResult(). Когда я вчера писал вам про Comsumer, я имел ввиду что вы обработку делаете в самом методе accept тогда, когда он вызовется. Это и есть асинхронная обработка результатов, вы же пытаетесь работать синхронно.

Если необходимо все таки сделать тест, то его можно модифицировать так (очень плохое решение, но для теста сойдет и  будет работать):

```
int sec = 5; //Кол-во секунд которые вы готовы ждать на поиск результата.
while (sec != 0){
   if (consumer.getResult() != null) break;
   Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
   sec--;
}
assertNotNull(consumer.getResult());
```

Comment: >>обработку делаете в самом методе accept тогда, когда он вызовется<< в каком смысле обработку? что вы имеете в виду под обработкой?

Comment: Всмысле вы же для чего-то искали файл. Вот нашли, у вас вызвался accept у Consumer-а вот тут же и делайте с ним то, что вы хотите согласно с вашей бизнес-логикой. Если вы все таки хотите, что бы по getResult() ваш поток (в котором вы вызовете этот метод) остановился, дождался когда файл найдется и вернул вам управление и результат, то реализация будет иная и сложней. Но я не вижу смысла в таком решении - блокировка потока это моветон.

Comment: По бизнес логике я должен получить объект File. Вот только как мне не ловить NPE?

Comment: Вы его и получаете в accept. В чем проблема там же дальше с ним работать? Не используя ни какие getResult()

Comment: Проблема только в том что мне надо протестировать что он пришел. Мне надо показать тестом что вот файл нашелся это он, и сдать задачу, и все. Ну еще потом двухсторонние зависимости как то убрать. А если я не где не показал что оно работает то как бы это сказать... вроде и не решил

Comment: я так понимаю что вопрос в том как мне узнать что все потоки отработали. Правильно?

Comment: Обновил ответ выше

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56537/discussion-between--and--).